# Simple Coverage Route not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that when I run my tests I am creating new files in my /cov folder

```
Finished in 20.6 seconds
19 examples, 0 failures
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/nicholasshook/Sites/<<my project>>/coverage. 264 / 446 LOC (59.19%) covered.
```

Done.

However, when I try going to localhost/coverage/index.html I get this error

```
No route matches [GET] "/coverage/index.html"
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is /coverage located? Under /controllers?

Comment: it's in the root of my rails app. I can try moving it to controllers.
edit: didn't change anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using SimpleCov or some similar gem to generate test results, those are static HTML files that are meant to be viewed locally on your machine.  I.E. just browse to /Users/nicholasshook/Sites/<>/coverage/index.html and open that file in your browser.

Rails won't create routes to /coverage/index.html for security and manageability reasons.  You can create a route to static html pages, but they must be in the /public directory.  If you need your coverage results to be accessible in your app, you have a few options:

1. Move your coverage file to the /public directory, and use a gem like High_Voltage   https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage to creat a route there
2. You'll need to either reconfigure your coverage tool to put files in the /public directory, or manually copy them over

Comment: high voltage did not work, it said that my index.html was not valid UTF-8. However moving the entire /coverage folder inside the public folder worked. Updated my .gitignore to reflect the changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this by using the following line just after SimpleCov.start 'rails' in my spec_helper.rb file.

```
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
SimpleCov.root('/my/app/root/directory/public')
```

You should also add /public/coverage to your .gitignore file

Answer (score 2):

Τhis breaks coverage. It would be better to:

```
cd public && ln -s ../coverage coverage
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `public` folder as root will change the scope of files for test coverage.
This worked for me

```
SimpleCov.start do
 SimpleCov.coverage_dir('public/coverage')
end
```